# Entity Framework : referencing other objects

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework, in-memory-database

I have a `Movie` class that has lists of `Actors` and `Directors`.
Whenever I'm creating a `Movie` (using a Rest API) that uses those, everything's fine.

But when I'm creating a second one with an already existing `Actor` / `Director`, my first `Movie` loses its reference to said `Actor`/`Director`.

How can I fix this so that it doesn't do that? Should I create a new class that references `Movies` and `Actors`/`Directors`? How should I do that?

Here's my class in case anything catches the eye.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Title { get; set; }
    public required List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public required List<Director> Directors { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework's InMemory database system.

Everything else seems to be working correctly. The `Movie` references `Actors` and `Directors`, but not the other way around, I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really provide the models for `Actor` and `Director` as well but, based on the behavior, I assume you set up 1:N relationships from `Actor`|`Director` to `Movie`, so each `Actor` and `Director` can only associate with a single `Movie`.  The relationship should be set up as many-to-many as a film can have multiple actors/directors and actors/directors can have multiple films, so `Actor`|`Director` should also have a `List<Movie> Movies` property instead of `Movie Movie` properties and/or the fluent config should be set up appropriately:

```
builder.Entity<Movie>
    .HasMany( m => m.Actors )
    .WithMany( a => a.Movies );
    // or, if no corresponding navigation properties on Movies
    // .WithMany();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you!  `Actor` and `Director` only have basic string attributes, which is why I didn't bother putting them in, plus I didn't want them to have access to `Movies`. `WithMany()` solved this issue.